# Joomla contact forms and modals/lightbox

Tags: forms, joomla, modal-dialog, contacts

There are actually two questions.

I use Joomla 3.4 with Bootstrap 3. I want to create a modal with a contact form inside.

Is this possible to achiev without an extension? 
Or there is a good contact form extension which can do that?

All free Joomla contact form extensions I found and testet for Joomla 3.x are not as good as, for example aicontact for Joomla 2.5.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to complete this old question.

I solved it in an other post:

[Joomla 3 use form in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481030/joomla-3-use-form-in-modal)

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want to create a contact-form, you should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); ?>
```

This code can be added to your template in the index.php - file (or in some other template override file if that is more appropriate).

then you can add a link like this in your module/article/component (depending on where you want to display this link):

```
<a class="modal" 
href="<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_contact&"
."view=contact&id=5&tmpl=component");?>" 
rel="{size: {x: 700, y: 500}, handler:'iframe'}"
>Contact form</a>
```

where 5 is an example id of the contact the form will be sent to. You also need to override the default contact view in your template, and add that the modal dialog is closed on submit.

Comment: Thank you.
Unfortunately it is not possible to add php code to articles or modules without some extra plugin.

Or have i misunderstood you?

Is there maybe some kind of Joomla given form class that you can insert in the articles which will create a functioning form?

Comment: Hi, i adjusted my answer, your question did not specify you wanted this link in a content article. You can still use this method, but, as i say in the answer, you need to add a line in the template index.php-file. I removed the php-code from the link, so it is pure html. Please try to clarify better what you want in your question.